# How to choose pairs of points on a line segment to maximize the sum of the values of each point pair?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

This is a problem that could be done with dynamic programming that has `O(n^3)` complexity, but I am wondering if there are more efficient ways to do this.

Let's assume that we have the following points on a line segment of length 10

**Points**: `[1, 3, 5, 9]`

**Line segment**: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

There is a value for each pair of points, for example:

```
[1, 3]: 2; [1, 5]: 4; [1, 9]: 3; [3, 5]: 1; [3, 9]: 5; [5, 9]: 3
```

We want to figure out *what is the maximum sum of selected point pairs such that each pair of points should be less than 5 points apart*.

In my above example, (`[1, 5]` is fine but `[3, 9]` is not) and different pairs cannot overlap with each other (`[[1, 5], [5, 9]]` is fine but `[[1, 5], [3, 5]]` is not).

The answer to this question is `[[1, 5], [5, 9]]` with sum `7`.

I can use dynamic programming to solve this problem. I start by choosing the relative closest point pairs and the less closest until the farthest pair. While proceeding, I use an `n*n` matrix to save the current results according to the former ones. This dynamic programming has time complexity `O(n^3)`.

I am wondering if there are more efficient ways of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

tldr, `O(n^2)`

You can use some graph algorithms:

Each of your points (say `p`) can be mapped as two nodes (`po` and `pc`):
`1o, 1c, 3o, 3c 5o, 5c, 9o, 9c` where `o` stands for opening, and `c` stands for closing.

Since you consider pairs

- every opening node can be connected to a close node for the cost you defined
- every close node can be connected to an opening node with cost 0 (to allow opening of a new pair)

e.g: in your case, the weighted edges are:

```
// user defined
w(1o, 3c) = 2
w(1o, 5c) = 4
w(3o, 5c) = 1
w(5o, 9c) = 3

// enable connection of pairs
w(1c, 1o) = 0
w(1c, 3o) = 0
w(1c, 5o) = 0
w(1c, 9o) = 0
w(3c, 3o) = 0
w(3c, 5o) = 0
w(3c, 9o) = 0
w(5c, 5o) = 0
w(5c, 9o) = 0
```

Notice that having an edge e(x, 9o) is useless, since we can't make any pair with the last point as first elem of the pair...

To those weighted edges, we can add an additional close node `S` which is connected to all opening nodes

```
w(S, 1o) = 0
w(S, 3o) = 0
w(S, 5o) = 0
w(S, 9o) = 0
```

We there have a DAG (direct acyclic graph) to which we want to find the longest path to any node from source `S`.

Algorithm should be in [O(E+V)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/) where `E` is number of edges and `V` number of vertices

Regarding the topological ordering, the points `p` by increasing value almost already define it: `p_c` should come before `p_o` since we can have an edge `(p_c, p_o)`

Below code is in `O(n^2)`, with `n` the number of points, since to connect pairs together we need to create an edge from every closing node to the following opening ones (about n(n+1)/2)

```js
//pseudocode: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/
function longest(V, E) {
  let max = -9000
  const dist = V.reduce((acc, v)=>(acc[v] = -9000, acc), [])
  dist[V[0]] = 0
  V.forEach(u => {
    E[u].forEach(([v, w]) => {
      if (dist[v] < dist[u] + w) {
        dist[v] = dist[u] + w
        if (dist[v] > max) {
          max = dist[v]
        }
      }
    })
  })
  return max
}
function buildVE () {
  const open = x => x+'o'
  const close = x => x+'c'
  const points = [0].concat([1, 3, 5, 9])
  //close occurs before open because 5c can link to 5o
  const V = [close(0)].concat(points.slice(1).flatMap(x => [close(x), open(x)]))
  const E = {}
  const addEdge = (a, b, w) => {
    E[a] = E[a] || []
    E[a].push([b, w])
  }
  addEdge(open(1), close(3), 2)
  addEdge(open(1), close(5), 4)
  addEdge(open(3), close(5), 1)
  addEdge(open(5), close(9), 3)

  for (let i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
    for (let j = i; j < points.length; ++j) {
      addEdge(close(points[i]), open(points[j]), 0)
    }
  }
  const last = points[points.length-1]
  E[open(last)] = []
  E[close(last)] = []
  return {V, E}
}
const {V, E} = buildVE()
console.log(longest(V, E))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an `O(R^2)` dynamic programming solution (`R` = coordinates range). That can be brought further down to `O(N^2)` (`N` = number of pairs) by doing coordinate compression.

Let's call `L[i][j]` the weight of the pair with maximum weight starting at `k >= i` and ending exactly on `j`. `L[i][j]` can be computed in `O(R^2)` by using the recursion `L[i][j] = max(W[i][j], L[i+1][j])`.

Now let's call `M[j]` the answer to your problem with the added restriction that the last pair (let's call it `Q`) ends exactly on `j`. Notice that if the answer is composed of more than one pair, there must be another pair in the answer ending on `k < j-1`. If that is so, then it must be that the solution for `M[j]` is the same solution as for `M[k]`, with `Q` appended in the end (otherwise we would be able to make `M[j]` bigger by using `M[k]` instead). Furthermore, `Q` must start in a coordinate `i > k` (since the pairs are non-overlapping), and it must be maximal, i.e. it's weight is `L[k+1][j]` (otherwise we would be able to make `M[j]` bigger by using `L[k+1][j]` instead of `Q`). There's also the special case when `M[j]` is composed of a single pair, in which case there's no such `k`.

With all that, we can make the recursion `M[j] = max(L[0][j], max(M[k] + L[k+1][j], for k in [1, j-2]))`. You can compute `M[j]` in `O(R^2)` with the recursion above.

The solution to your problem will be `max(M[j], for j in [0, R))`. To bring it down to `O(N^2)`, just sort all the coordinates (in `O(N log N)`), then map them to coordinates in `[0, 2*N)` (in `O(N)` using a hash map), since the only thing that matters to the problem is their order.